# Loading static files in Express

Tags: css, node.js, express

I have been trying to get my node.JS file to serve my HTML app with static CSS and JS files included too but have ran into great difficulties (the HTML file is loading, but with no styling). From my searching it seems the main recommended method is to add the Express middleware to your node.JS and then add this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static/')));
```

Before I go on too much further I will show you my directory set-up:

```
-static
    -images
        -favicon
            -favicon.png
        -logo.png
    -style
        -design.css
        -theme.css
        -w3.css
    -source
        -client
            -style.js
-node_modules
    -...
-index.html
-root.js
-package-lock.json
-...
```

The 'root.js' file is my node.JS file that I am running and it serves the 'index.html' page, but all the CSS and JS files my HTML page links to come up with this sort of error...

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/static/style/design.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

Here is one example of a line in my 'index.html' where I try to link to that CSS file...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style/design.css">
```

...and here is where 'index.html' is served in my 'root.js' file...

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

I am not too sure where I am going wrong as most guides on the topic seem to imply that when I add in the magic '__dirname' line to my node.JS that everything is meant to resolve itself. When I just run my HTML page locally by opening it in Chrome or Firefox it works fine. I am hoping you might be able to explain to me where I am going wrong, thank you.

Comment: href should be `/style/design.css` not `static/style/design.css`. Also if you move `index.html` inside your static directory, you don't need to serve it seperately.

Comment: To the first part I had tried that (and did try again) but it still comes up with identical error messages and also means that when I open the HTML page locally through a browser that it will be looking in the wrong place for my CSS files etc. As for the second part I am not sure what you mean as I still have to have a block of code that serves something right?

Comment: Well it looks like you're trying to run two different servers (which you shouldn't be). Delete the `http.createServer()`, move `index.html` into your `static` directory, change the `href` to `/style/design.css` (or `style/design.css` without the leading forward slash, which would allow `index.html` to be opened locally as well), and call `app.listen(8080)` instead. Right now it looks like you're not calling that anywhere since you have the other `http` server running instead of `express`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I see where I went wrong now and it all works now, thank you!